# Force relative path in media library for LAN deployment

Tags: uploads, media, localhost, xampp

I have created a Xampp powered local wordpress install. This will be used at my work as a sort of "intranet" using LAN - I have no intentions of deploying it on a server, as it is not required by what we need it for.

Right now, all computers type in the IP address to the hosting computer ie. 192.168.x.xx:80/wordpress -- this works great, however, the images do not appear - I believe this is because the other computers are looking for http://localhost:80/wordpress/wp-content../img.jpg

Of course this confuses the computer because it thinks it's the localhost. Is there a way I can force the items in the media library to be relative paths? This would also have to automatically make new uploads relative as well. I know this isn't necessary desired in most circumstances, but I would need it for this one.

I have changes the site URL to the IP of the computer, but this causes the host computer to be unable to log in, and I don't want to have my co-workers have to do this each time we switch the host computer.
Thanks all for looking, I appreciate any ideas or answers.

Comment: what do you have entered as the values for 'home' and 'siteurl' options (Settings > General)?

Comment: This doesn't work because your WP siteurl is defined as localhost/wordpress instead of it's base IP. Basically, if you right click -> inspect element on any of the images, you'll see their paths are set to localhost/wordpress.

I'm afraid there's no relative paths, at the moment, unfortunately but you could give this a shot: try changing your site URL to 192.168.0.1/wordpress (or whatever your IP is for localhost).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have changed my siteurl to the 192.168.x.xx - and it does work on the computers that aren't the host. but for some reason, it makes it so the host computer cannot login. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think this should be a different question.